# How to Kick off a Task with just 1 predecessor complete

Tags: ms-project, tasks

So I have Task A,B,C,

Task B is based on CSF-5, (needs to have finish date 5 days prior to C date), but I want the task to kick off as soon as Task A is completed.

Is there a way to set that?

Right now, it needs A and C to be completed, because they are both under predecessors.

Comment: You'd like to change the dependency (ignoring then the C dependency) or you want to have BOTH criteria met or you want to have ANY of the criteria met?

Comment: I want both criteria met

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make Project do what you want.
Project will always move the task around to meet dependencies. It will change the Start Date, but not lengthen the task or shorten it. 
A FS dependency does not mean "start Task B exactly when Task A is finished" but "don't start Task B before Task A is finished". So Task B must wait until Task A is finished, but can also start later.
If you have two or more dependencies, the latest start date will apply and all dependencies will be considered respected.